# How do you rename a local 'external' in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I've recently added an external file to a directory that is being tracked in SVN. We're using tortoiseSVN. Typically when we add externals, we try to give it a prefix marking such that others know it's an external. However, I accidentally forgot the prefix.

When attempting to rename the file, it doesn't give me the dropdown option in TortoiseSVN like it does for other non-external files.

TLDR: How do you change the local name of an SVN external in TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, I was able to figure out how to solve this.

Go to the folder that have the externals as properties. Right click 'properties', go the 'Subversion' tab, click on the 'Properties' button. Highlight the property called 'externals'. Click on it and edit the path/change the name. You've just primed SVN to make the changes on the next update. Go ahead and update and the local file name will have changed.